# Computing pairwise intersection of corresponding polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have two polygon layers - call them Layer 1 and Layer 2. Conceptually speaking, they represent two different versions of the same dataset.

I want to perform pairwise Boolean operations on corresponding polygons in each layer. That is, I want a single layer which contains the union/intersection/difference/... of every pair of polygons with the same value of an attribute.

In the following example, I have Layer 1 and Layer 2 and I want to generate the two features in the pairwise intersection layer:

[image: Example of what I am looking for]

Conceptually, the pairwise intersection shows me the areas of land that have remained in polygons A and B between the two versions of the dataset. (In reality my layers have many more than 3 polygons.)

I have written an R script to solve this problem, but **I am wondering if there is a way to do it entirely using the QGIS user interface**.

In recent versions, QGIS has a feature that allows you to iterate over every feature of a layer, but I can't see how this can be applied in this situation. What's more, the QGIS Graphical Modeler doesn't seem to support loops.

Comment: The symmetrical difference should do the trick (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#symmetrical-difference). But you still need to take of it paring part before you use the tool and that you can do with using python in QGIS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `DB Manager` standard plug-in and SQL query on your project layers (even if these are not stored in an RDBMS). I suppose your layers have an `id` column which is a unique identifier for the features.

1. Open the two layers (I draw something similar to your layers) using `new` and `old` for layer names
   [image]
2. Enable `DB Manager` plug-in `Plugins/Manage and Install Plugins...` from the menu
3. Open `DB Manager` using `Database/DB Manager...` from the menu
4. Open the `Virtual Layers` and `Project layers` (if your data is in Geopackage or PostGIS or SpatiaLite open the other group)
5. Select the second icon from the toolbar of `DB Manager` (spanner icon)
6. Input the following SQL command:

   select new.id, st_intersection(new.geometry, old.geometry) as geometry
   from new inner join old on (new.id = old.id)
   [image]
7. Click on `Execute` and check `Load as new layer`
8. Check `Column with unique values` and select `id` column and check `Geometry column` and select `geometry`
9. Finally click on `Load` button

You should get a `Query_layer` in your project with the result:
[image]

Comment: There is still coding involved here, but of course the problem becomes so simple when you break it down using spatial SQL, so it's well worth it! Great answer.